# Dynamically creating a list in Ansible with jinja

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-playbook, jinja

I need to dynamically set a new list type variable list var.

Here's a basic playbook example:

```
  vars:
    app_instances:
      - host_name: host1-domain
        inst_count: 3
      - host_name: host2-domain
        inst_count: 1
      - host_name: host3-domain
        inst_count: 1

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        instance_config: >-
          {% set inst_config = [] %}
          {% for inst in app_instances %}
            {% for inst_num in range(inst.inst_count) %}
              {% set node_number = inst.host_name.split('-') | first | replace('host', '') %}
              {% set host_name = "host_name" %}
              {% set host_num = "host_num" %}
              {% set inst_name = "inst_name" %}
              {% set node_conf = { host_name: inst.host_name, host_num: node_number, inst_name: inst_num+1 } %}
              {{ inst_config.append(node_conf) }}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {{ inst_config|join(",") }}

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ instance_config }}"
```

This obviously sets the `instance_config` to a string with the following contents:

```
"instance_config": "                           \n                          \n                          \n                            \n                            \n   {'host_name': 'host1-domain', 'host_num': '1', 'inst_name': 1},{'host_name': 'host1-domain', 'host_num': '1', 'inst_name': 2},{'host_name': 'host1-domain', 'host_num': '1', 'inst_name': 3},{'host_name': 'host2-domain', 'host_num': '2', 'inst_name': 1},{'host_name': 'host3-domain', 'host_num': '3', 'inst_name': 1}"
```

So while the structure of the list that I'm getting is correct, it's a String and I can't seem to make this into a variable that would be a list instead.
What Am I missing here? What I need eventually is a variable:

```
instance_config = [
  {'host_name': 'host1-domain', 'host_num': '1', 'inst_name': 1},
  {'host_name': 'host1-domain', 'host_num': '1', 'inst_name': 2},
  {'host_name': 'host1-domain', 'host_num': '1', 'inst_name': 3},
  {'host_name': 'host2-domain', 'host_num': '2', 'inst_name': 1},
  {'host_name': 'host3-domain', 'host_num': '3', 'inst_name': 1}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question as I have found a solution:

1. enable `do` jinja extension in ansible.cfg: `jinja2_extensions = jinja2.ext.do`
2. replace `{{ inst_config.append(node_conf) }}` with `{% do inst_config.append(node_conf) %}`
3. trim whitespaces using `{%-` and `-%}`.

The final result of the `set_fact` task looks like this:

```
    - set_fact:
        instance_config: >-
          {%- set instance_config = [] -%}
          {%- for inst in app_instances -%}
            {%- for inst_num in range(inst.inst_count) -%}
              {%- set node_number = inst.host_name.split('-') | first | replace('host', '') | int -%}
              {%- set host_name = "host_name" -%}
              {%- set host_num = "host_num" -%}
              {%- set inst_name = "inst_name" -%}
              {%- set node_conf = { host_name: inst.host_name, host_num: node_number, inst_name: inst_num+1 } -%}
              {%- do instance_config.append(node_conf) -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {{ instance_config }}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach to a similar problem using builtin `union` filter:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    app_instances:
      - host_name: host1-domain
        inst_count: 3
      - host_name: host2-domain
        inst_count: 1
      - host_name: host3-domain
        inst_count: 1

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        instance_config: >-
          {{ instance_config | default([]) | union(app_instances) }}
    # just to demo that with approach could be used anywhere, without
    # worrying about overriding previously set values
    - set_fact:
        instance_config: >-
          {{ instance_config | default([]) | union(['more', 'items']) }}

    - debug:
        var: instance_config
```

Worth noting that any array modifications are not applied for clarity but should be easy to adopt.

My case was about gathering systemd unit names, which were generated dynamically by a few, independent from each other, roles.